# Shadow of an edge of a surface of revolution

Tags: projective-geometry

A surface of revolution meridian $ r= f(z) $ has laterally incident sunshine.

What should be $f,$ if the shadow cast by edge $ z= a $ on its inner surface has a terminator always remaining in a plane?

EDIT1:

I had verified paraboloid as a particular solution but what is the general case? Does it happen to every surface of revolution?

[image: ShadowTerminator]